# How many levels of sub-categories can be created?

Tags: category

Surprisingly I couldn't find an answer with a bit of googling. I am really trying to understand the level of categories and nested subcategories that magento allows.

Thank you,
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a limit in Magento itself, but it can come up from DB.

Considering that "path" field in `catalog_category_entity` is a `varchar(255)` and a `/` is used a separator and the first 3 chars are usually for root categories you have:

```
(255 - 3) / 2 = 126
```

So I think you cannot have more than 126 nested levels... I think it is enough ;)